# CPLEX C++ get the index of variable by variable name

Tags: c++, cplex

Is it possible in CPLEX optimizer, with c++ api, to get the index of a variable by the variable name? I couldn't find any suitable method to do that. Plz help.

I have [IloNumVarArray vars;] variable to store variables by name.

vars[i].getName(); // gives the name of the variable at index i

Is there any method like : vars.getIndex(name), which can give the index of the variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM CPLEX - How to get back a reference to a named variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316845/ibm-cplex-how-to-get-back-a-reference-to-a-named-variable)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything like that in CPLEX.

You can always iterate the array and compare the name to get back your variable. If you need better performance you can use a map.

Comment: yeah, I couldn't find anything like that. I also thought about map. But I wanted to be sure about that. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the callable library C++ API, there is function for finding the column index, given a column name:

> int CPXgetcolindex(CPXCENVptr env, CPXCLPptr lp, const char *
>   lname_str, int * index_p)

See:

[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2Frefcallablelibrary%2Fhtml%2Ffunctions%2FCPXaddmipstarts.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/html/functions/CPXaddmipstarts.html)